# Displaying custom image in android: XML config

Tags: android

I have an XML file in my android directory -

```
        <ImageView
            android:tint="#F00"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxWidth="50dp"
            android:maxHeight="50dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info"/>
```

I want to use my own custom image in place of `"@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info"`. I have my own JPEG/PNG image on my disk (for eg. at /home/abcd/images/icon.png).

How do I specify this in XML? How do I configure my XML such that `icon.png` is picked up in place of `ic_dialog_info` ?

Comment: This is a completely newbie-type question. Find some tutorial for imageview and image loading in android. a quick google search will do the work.

Comment: But if you need a hint.. then you need to put that image file in drawable folder.. then you can give the reference of `R.drawable.your_image` instead of `android@drawa....`